# WEB API to return object following serialization attributes

Tags: serialization, asp.net-web-api

I am using WEB API to return an object (class).

Class is already being structured using System.Xml.Serialization attributes, which makes if difficult to return entire class using WEB API, since it exposes more then it should. I don't think it is a solution to serialize class and return a string, so I want to return a serializable object.

Here is a short example of my class

```
                [XmlIgnore]
                [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
                public SettingEnums.currencyCodesEnum currency
                {
                    get;
                    set;
                }

                [XmlAttributeAttribute("currency")]
                public string Serializablecurrency
                {
                    get { return this.currency.ToString(); }
                    set { }
                }
```

How can I return serializable object that follows serialization attributes defined in this class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET Web API does use the serialization attributes defined at the class level. However, `XmlMediaTypeFormatter` uses `DataContractSerializer` by default. Since you are using `XmlSerializer`, you need to tell Web API to use the same, like this.

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters
                      .XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```